# Why is run method not called?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

```
package threadwork;

public class WorkingWithThreads implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WorkingWithThreads wwt = new WorkingWithThreads();
    }

    public WorkingWithThreads() {
        System.out.println("Creating Thread");
        Thread t = new Thread();
        System.out.println("Starting Thread");
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread Running");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread:" + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it Prints Creating Thread and Starting Thread. But doesn't prints Thread Running, that means run function is not at all called. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `start()` on the thread to get it to start; e.g.

```
Thread t = new Thread();
t.start();
```

If you were extending `Thread`, you would create a new thread and call `start()` on it like this:

```
new MyThread().start();
```

Since you are not extending `Thread`, but your class implements `Runnable`:

```
new Thread(new WorkingWithThreads()).start();
```

Comment: I did t.start(), forgot to write it here.

Comment: And you need to create the instance of the class that extends thread. See my edit in the answer

Comment: I am not extending Thread, I am implementing Runnable Interface. And in main I have created the instance of the class that is implementing Runnable interface.

Comment: Ok, Java is not my forte. See edit in my answer again when implementing Runnable

Comment: It works but now I have a doubt. I place the last code by you before creating the thread, i.e before Thread t = new Thread(). Now run is called only once, why so, I have two threads here and am calling the start method twice.

Comment: Because the thread t that you create doesn't have any clue about the WorkingWithThreads that you have written and calls the Thread::run() not WorkingWithThreads::run(). You can remove that line. Or remove the line I suggested and use Thread t = new Thread(new WorkingWithThreads()); t.start();

Comment: And yeah,like phooji suggests, move it to main() and not have it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your shoes, I would start the thread inside main, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  WorkingWithThreads wwt = new WorkingWithThreads();
  System.out.println("Creating Thread");
  Thread tzero = new Thread(wwt);
  System.out.println("Starting thread");
  tzero.start();
}
```

Leaving the constructor for `WorkingWithThreads` empty:

```
public WorkingWithThreads() {
  System.out.println("Creating Runnable");
}
```

In general, it is not a good idea to create the `Thread` inside the constructor for `WorkingWithThreads`, because the runnable (i.e., an instance of `WorkingWithThreads`) must be fully constructed *before* you pass it to an instance of `Thread`.